# WebDAV on server exposing ZFS data from another server

Tags: linux, nginx, storage, freebsd, webdav

Is it even possible to have WebDAV server hosted on one computer and its pulling the "data" (folders and files and all) from another server?

Something like so:

```
                      CentOS Proxy
                           |
              -------------|--------------
              |            |              |
          FreeBSD1     FreeBSD2        FreeBSD3
        (ZFS Store)  (ZFS Store)      (ZFS Store)
```

Where the CentOS proxy is the WebDAV server that every connection would access to see the files, where the files are actually stored on the FreeBSD ZFS servers?  The files on the FreeBSD servers will be chrooted to each user/group.

If it is even possible, how would one go about it and is there a proper name for it? I'm fed up with people looking at me funny when I ask them this.

Our preference is to use NGINX, but we'll happily look at apache.

Also, how would this (ZFS on FreeBSD) compare with GlusterFS on CentOS/XFS or for that matter GlusterFS on FreeBSD/ZFS.

If it makes any difference, each ZFS store is planned to run RAID-Z except for two which will run RAID-Z3  (there are in fact more than three and the idea is to be able to organically grow by adding new servers)

We would love to see some sort of self-healing ability a la OpenStack Swift, but that would be the ideal.

TIA

Comment: Are the three FreeBSD systems serving the same data?

Comment: @ewwhite no, but there is the possibility that they might share data, especially amongst team members, hence the preference for ZFS since we could dedup it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just remotely mount the ZFS filesystems on the proxy machine (using NFS/CIFS/whatever) and then run a WEBDAV server which serves the mountpoints.

Comment: Really? That simple? Didn't really cross my mind to do something like that.  I'll give it a try the moment that I can.  Thanks.